# SumIf formula with Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Sumif formula, it seems not working when i am trying with sheets, its just giving me the code without any sheets

```
Dim rCritera As Range
Dim rCriteriaRange As Range
Dim rSum As Range
Dim rFormula As Range


Set rCriteriaRange = Wb.Sheets("Change").Range("A:A")
Set rCritera = Wb.Sheets("Waterfall").Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(0, -9)
Set rSum = Wb.Sheets("Change").Range("M:M")

Set rFormula = ActiveCell 

rFormula.Formula = "=SumIf(" & rCriteriaRange.Address(1, 1) & "," & rCritera.Address(0, 0) & "," & rSum.Address(0, 0) & ")"
```

Comment: rFormula = Application.WorksheetFunction.sumif(rCriteriaRange, rCritera, rSum)

Comment: Thank you so much Brax, but i want it in a formula base not in fixed values base coz i have to fill to down as well as well fill right Like so my formula criteria will (M:M) in current cell & changes to (N:N) next column

Comment: I think you were referring to @ScriptDeveloper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused given you're using `ActiveCell` and working across sheets.
What you're looking for and where it exists isn't 100% clear ... I think this is what you need though ...

`rFormula.Formula = "=SumIf('Change'!" & rCriteriaRange.Address & "," & rCritera.Address & ",'Change'!" & rSum.Address & ")"`

Comment: @Deeraj, you need to flag one as the answer then.  It rewards those who help and also helps others along the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
rFormula.Formula = "=SumIf(Change!" & rCriteriaRange.Address(1, 1) & "," & rCritera.Address(0, 0) & ",Change!" & rSum.Address(0, 0) & ")"
```